# Android app: text getting cropped on smaller devices

Tags: android, image, crop

We are developing an android app. The text displaying properly on 5" devices. But getting cropped on smaller devices (4", 3.5"). why is it happening? Any help welcome. Please see screenshots below. "Credit" "Debit" and "Net" displayed instead of "Credit Card" "Debit Card" and "Net Banking" in screenshot below.

[image: on bigger devices]

[image: on smaller devices]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff" >
    <include android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              layout="@layout/sdk_header"
              />

 <RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/topLogoLayout" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp" 
      android:layout_marginRight="0dp" 
      android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
      android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp" 
      android:background="#e5e5e5" 
      android:paddingTop="10dp" 
      android:paddingBottom="20dp">

  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/youtxt" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
      android:gravity="right" 
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:text="You"
 android:textSize="40sp" 
 android:textColor="#727272" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" /> 

 <RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/arrowLayout" 
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/youtxt"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/companyLogo"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/txt_amount" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
      android:text="Rs. 10" 
      android:textColor="#727272" 
      android:textSize="18sp" /> 

   <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/arrow" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="18dp" 
      android:src="@drawable/arrow" 
      android:layout_below="@+id/txt_amount" /> 

  </RelativeLayout>

  <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/companyLogo" 
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
      android:layout_marginRight="30dp" 
      android:layout_width="70dp" 
      android:layout_height="50dp" 
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
      android:src="@drawable/wallet_logo" 
      android:scaleType="fitXY" /> 
  </RelativeLayout>

  <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/orange_line"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
      android:src="@drawable/orange_line" 
      /> 
  <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator 
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:id="@+id/indicator" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/pager" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show xml code and relative java code. Try setting singleLine to false for textviews if that helps.

Comment: Possibly you are setting the TextViews by using margin. So better use weight.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when there is not enough space on the screen to show the full text?

Comment: please show your xml code and java code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex topic on which a book could be written (and probably has). I'll focus on the only problem I can see: text size.

It seems that your fonts are too big on the small screen. This affects what appear to be tabs and buttons, although the EditText has the problem too (it just doesn't overflow).

The useful way of measuring screen size is the sw-dp (shortest width device independent pixel). The dp density is adjusted so that it is around 160dpi on all devices. For a 5" tablet that will be around a 3" width and it should be an sw480dp device. The 3"-3.5" screen has around a 2" width and should be an sw320dp device.

To make this work at the simplest level, you need to place some text size settings in your `value-sw240dp` folder that are about 3/4 of the text size for your default sw480dp device.

For example, this might appear in your `dimen` file in that folder.

```
<dimen name="view_field_text_size">14sp</dimen>
```

I can't give you a cookbook because I have no info about your other use of styles or dimensions. Perhaps in a layout you might have:

```
<EditText
   <android:textSize="@dimen/view_field_text_size"
/>
```

It's better to put it in a style, but that's outside the scope here.

Answer (score 0):

Different devices may have different *pixel density, screen size, Orientation, Resolution and Density-independent pixel (dp)*.

**Solution** -

- Define different layout files for different screen sizes.
- Ensuring your layout can be adequately resized to fit the screen
- Providing appropriate UI layout according to screen configuration
- Ensuring the correct layout is applied to the correct screen

By default, Android resizes your application layout to fit the current device screen. In most cases, this works fine. In other cases, your UI might not look as good and might need adjustments for different screen sizes. For example, on a larger screen, you might want to adjust the position and size of some elements to take advantage of the additional screen space, or on a smaller screen, you might need to adjust sizes so that everything can fit on the screen.

The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.

Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in layout-sw600dp/. Using the new techniques for declaring layout resources is discussed further in the section about Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2.

Look - [Multiple Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)  and [Support Screen training docs](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create different folders related to density or screen size like

Option 1.

```
values-large
values-small
values-normal
```

For more explanation check this link...

[Multiple Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Option 2.

```
mTextView.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

this will give TextSize depending on density..

Comment: Option 2: what has the density to do with the screen size?

Comment: getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density of Device

Comment: Yes, but you can have small screens with high density and large screens with low density. Your option2 would make the text larger on the small screen.